# CallEvent() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, arguments

I did a lot of research and I also did various things to the code but without success, I know it's a dumb question but I can't get rid of this please ?

The code

```
    def CallEvent(self):
    super(SubTitleBar, self).CallEvent("SubTitleBar")
    self.OnClickEvent()
```

The error :

```
CallEvent() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Thanks and have a nice day ! :)

Comment: Use `super(SubTitleBar, self).CallEvent()`

Comment: Thanks ! :) It's solved

Answer (score 1):

When you use a dot, the thing before is passed as the first argument (usuanlly denoted as `self` or `cls` in method signature. So basically you called this function like this:

```
CallEvent(super(SubTitleBar, self), "SubTitleBar")
```

and Python rightly complained, that you passed two arguments.